# Node.js crashed for some reason

Tags: javascript, node.js

So Im getting this error:

```
[18:12:49:550] Message: "SEND items to user."
confirmTrade() received 1 confirmations
confirmTrade(): true
[18:13:8:154] Message: "Send all game number, jackpot 0"
[18:13:8:155] Message: "Starting to send informers for each socket"
[18:13:8:163] Message: "Send all "start-game""
undefined:1
<!doctype html>
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request._callback (/home/bot/bot.js:476:20)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:354:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1207:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1153:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you tried to run an html file with Node.js. Don't.